# How to display secondary widget area for specific category in sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I use the code below to display secondary widgets. This code shows all recent posts in the sidebar but I want a secondary widget for a specific category.

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'secondary-widget-area' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register/declare your widgetized area before you can use it. This happens in the `functions.php`, so that your theme is aware of the widget area.

```
<?php
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Home right sidebar',
    'id' => 'home_right_1',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
?>
```

If you're just trying to add a secondary widget to an existing widgetized area, then no coding is needed. Just go to `Appearance>Widgets` and drag and drop HTML blocks or other custom widgets to the appropriate area.

[More on Using Widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets)

[More on Widgetizing](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)